# How can i Load only a selected part of webpage in chrome when it load by JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My problem is that i want to remove all other content from a webpage except some div just like something in read only mode of browser.

Is it possible to remove all other HTML element just like `<script>...</script>` ,  `<div>...</div>`

except some div class that i want to keep on page like:  `<div class="someone">...</div>`

i tried this one : [How can i remove all div's and other DOM HTML elements except a particular class using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66156022/how-can-i-remove-all-divs-and-other-dom-html-elements-except-a-particular-class) but not completing my target :

is there some best tips available to done my job.

Comment: You can make it only with SSR (server side rendering). Try PHP for example or python+django, not with client javascript

Comment: is it possible with JS or Jquery

Comment: With JS or Jquery that means it's not your page or project ...

Comment: It is possible with nodejs, not with jquery

Comment: i mean After page get load can we do something that remove all element but keep some one

Comment: @ZloiGoroh Can you explain with example how can i do with nodejs ? plz humble request

Comment: Well, you can use `remove` method. I am not sure if it would work with `not` pseudoclass, but you can make a recursion function, that will check all elements on your page

Comment: plz give me code for that i pray to you

Comment: Hi ! Are you doing web scraping on the client side ? Why don't you just grab only the relevant parts ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it this way to remove everything but your wanted elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $('.exclude');
  $('body').html(x);
});
```

Here is a sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $('.exclude');
  $('body').html(x);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="exclude">Excluded heading</h1>
<p>I will disappear.</p>
<p class="exclude">I will remain in the page.</p>
<p class="exclude">Me Too!</p>
<p>Some text...</p>
<p>Some text...</p>

Some text...Some text...Some text...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya really this is nice way, 
But can i use this for multi class like this ```  var x = $('.exclude' , 'exclude2');```
any way ?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many class as you want by using this syntax: `var x = $('.exclude.exclude2.exclude3');`.

Comment: really thnx man